# Received Memory Warning with UICollectionView to view Images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, alassetslibrary

I have created a UICollectionView to view ALAssets horizontally. ALAssets are first stored to a MutableArray called `assets`. Then the collection View display those Assets by this method.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    AssetCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MY_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
    UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
    cell.imageView.image = largeimage;

    return cell;
}
```

But the assets collection is more than 100 images, the app gives a memory Warning for me. Memory usage also increased more than 50MB. How can get rid of this huge memory usage? What is the wrong thing I'm doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you miss a release of the CGImage you create.

```
ALAsset *asset = self.assets[indexPath.row];
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation]; 
CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage]; //! creates
UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
cell.imageView.image = largeimage;
CGImageRelease(iref); //! release
```

Comment: a side note: dont ever load more than 1 fullScreenImage and dont ever display fullResolutionImages unless you really need to

Comment: + listen to didReceiveMemoryWarnings (especially if you work with big images)

Comment: last but not least: lazy always wins.. load it only when you really need it - cellForItem is called too soon, too often and the items are cached for too long

Comment: still I'm getting the memory warning. Shall I reduce the quality of fullResolutionImage & then display??

Comment: but also see the three tips -- mainly the third one. dont do it in cellForItem. Do it in a custom imageview that only loads it when it is shown

Comment: I have to use cellForItem because there may be 100+ Assets to display. Only ScrollView with imageviews are not enough.

Comment: yes, but instead of using a UIImageView, have the cell use a MyCustomAssetView. load a thumbnail into it and have it only load the fullScreenImage if it is displayed

Comment: you would have to write a custom cell class & imageview class but than you can do more lazy loading (like photos app for example)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid creating UIImage objects that are greater than 1024 x 1024 in size. (Apple SDK guide)
I guess it's because you try to load lots of large images at a time.

So, if you just want to show images in master collection view, you can use thumbnail images of ALAsset class instead.

When user touched one of images, show the 'fullResolutionImage' at that time.